# Create a stream reader in c# console to read only one student at a time instead of all of them using a .txt file

Tags: c#, console, streamreader

```
class Program
{
    static string strFile = "Student Database.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string strInput = null; // user input string

    start:
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("student_results.txt");

        // Request user input as to actions to be carried out
        Console.WriteLine("\nWhat do you want to do?\n" +
            " 1.View Student(s)\n 2.Add a New Student\n 3.Exit program");
        // Save user input to make decision on program operation
        strInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // Switch statement checking the saved user input to decide the action
        // to be carried out
        switch (strInput)
        {
            case "1": // choice for view file
                Console.Clear();

                string file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +
                    @"student_results.txt";
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
                string wholeFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(wholeFile + "");
                sr.Close();

                goto start;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I want this part of my code to just read the students indivially and relay them back to me, instead of how it is doing so at the moment were it just calls all of them back to me when I press '1) view Student' it pretty much says "please enter the students name or ID number of which student you would like to view".
I've currently have got the ID number running off a random number generator.

Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: What is the format of the input file?

Comment: Why on Earth are you using goto?

Comment: Suggestion: Remove the `goto`. They are a no-no. Use a loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, first of all `goto` is not a good choice in C# in 99% of cases, and you'd better use loops. For your code I would save each student in a single line and at the time of reading students I would read them line by line untill I found the student.

```
class Program
{
    static string strFile = "Student Database.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strInput = ""; // user input string

        while (strInput != "3")
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("student_results.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("\nWhat do you want to do?\n 1.View Student(s)\n 2.Add a New Student\n 3.Exit program"); // request user input as to actions to be carried out
            strInput = Console.ReadLine(); //save user input to make decision on program operation

            switch (strInput)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID: \n");
                    string file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"student_results.txt";
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
                    string StudentID = Console.ReadLine();
                    string line = "";
                    bool found = false;
                    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.Split(',')[0] == StudentID)
                        {
                            found = true;
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    if (!found)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student ID : ");
                    string SID = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name : ");
                    string SName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Average : ");
                    string average = Console.ReadLine();
                    string wLine = SID + "," +SName+":"+average;
                    file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"student_results.txt";
                    StreamWriter sw = File.Exists(file) ? File.AppendText(file) : new StreamWriter(file);
                    sw.WriteLine(wLine);
                    sw.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Student saved on file, press a key to continue ...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Command!\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code might not be complete, I wanted to give you the idea, I hope it helps.

Comment: Plus one for saying there are (although extremely rare) cases where goto makes sense.

Comment: This is pretty much what I am after, thank you.
All I need to do is incoperate my 12 course modules which are split in the middle year 1, 6 modules year 2, 6 modules and then divide them by 12 to get an average % mark over the 2 year. 

But again this is what im after. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are not dealing with a huge file of students, and on the basis that you want to make multiple queries, i would not read the text file line by line each time.

Instead create a student class, read the file once on init, and create a list< student > from the data. Then you can query it with LinQ

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadStudents
{
    class Program
    {
        static string _filename = "students.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

            // Load students.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_filename);
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                students.Add( new Student( reader.ReadLine()));
            reader.Close();

            string action; 
            bool showAgain = true;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("1. See all students.");
                Console.WriteLine("2. See student by ID.");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Add new student.");
                Console.WriteLine("0. Exit.");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                action = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (action)
                {
                    case "1":
                        foreach (Student item in students)
                            item.Show();
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        Console.Write("ID = ");
                        int id = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() ); // TODO: is valid int?

                        foreach (Student item in students)
                            if (item.Id == id)
                                item.Show();
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("ID-Name");

                        Student newStudent = new Student(Console.ReadLine());
                        students.Add(newStudent);

                        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_filename, true);
                        writer.WriteLine(newStudent);
                        writer.Close();

                        break;

                    case "0":
                        Console.WriteLine("Bye!");
                        showAgain = false;

                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong action!");
                        break;

                }
            }
            while (showAgain);
        }
    }

    class Student
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;

        public Student(string line)
        {
            string[] fields = line.Split('-');

            Id = int.Parse(fields[0]);
            Name = fields[1];
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Id + ". " + Name);
        }
    }
}
```

I assume your data are in "ID-Name" format for example:

```
1-Alexander
2-Brian
3-Christian
```

I load file line-by-line and pass to Student class which converts in constructor text data to more friendly form. Next, application shows interface until user write "0".